# Java String contains not working with string parsed from file

Tags: java, string, file, encoding

I'm currently facing a string encoding problem.

```
ListItemType liste = new ListItemType();
    String toBChecked=(String)table.getValueAt(row,0);
    System.out.print(toBChecked);
    toBChecked =  "Angelic";
    for(String s : liste.sets){
        if(toBChecked.contains(s)){
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

When I copy/paste  the string "Angelic" from logs and put it in toBChecked it doesn't work, but when I type it in my code it does work.
Of course, when I directly check table's value (which has the "Angelic" word in its string) it doesn't work.

Table's content is parsed from a file encoded in UTF-16-LE, is it the problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: You should look *very carefully* at the string value. Look at its length, and output every character, casting each char to int to see the value. It doesn't help that we can't see the code that's reading this file...

Comment: I'm using Scanner object like this : new Scanner(path,"UTF-8") and store each lines in a String ArrayList.

Comment: You’re using `new Scanner(path, "UTF-8")` to read a file which you know is a UTF-16LE file?  Is there a reason for using a different charset?

Comment: I actually wanted to convert the encoding. That's a solution I found on web. But it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Well we don't know what that solution is, or in what it's not working... but reading the file using the wrong encoding is definitely a bad start.